# Sitemap in Subfolder

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, subdirectory

I have a Wordpress site (single page) on the root domain and another Wordpress site on a subfolder for my blog. The single page on the root domain does not link to the blog in the subfolder, nor do I want it to.

The question is, should I have 2 site maps, one in the root folder and one in the blog subfolder? If I only need one in the root domain, how do I go about making sure that the blog subfolder is included in the root sitemap?

And should I have both the root URL and the blog subfolder URL showing separately in Google Webmaster tools?

Would appreciate some input on this as I'm really confused. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure to the web/bots/engines pages are all independent items on the web. We logically group them for ourselves. If you treat them as two different sites, sitemap them as such and treat them as such, but I would suggest you make the other one a sub-domain for ease of understanding to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

> “I have a Wordpress site (single page) on the root domain and another Wordpress site on a
>   subfolder for my blog.” - ltm778

Seems like a lot of work. You should try setting your root domains WordPress install, custom structures option to something like "blog". Considering your root urls WordPress install consists of one page, you could write "blog post's" from within that root urls WordPress install that look a little something like this *www.thisismydomain.com/blog/hello-world/*.

> “The question is, should I have 2 site maps, one in the root folder and one in the blog subfolder?” - ltm778

I am not too sure on how all search engine robots handle looking for sitemaps, if whether they only look in the root directory or also search sub-path directory's. There are tools however that help aide you in submitting multiple sitemaps. You can have sitemaps in different sub-path directory's, but it doesn't make it good practice. You can even submit multiple sitemaps that are found under one domain to Google Webmaster.

It's extra work running two WordPress sites, but you can have two different installs, and you can have each install have it's own sitemap that you would later submit to Google Webmsater Tools. Google XML Sitemap Generator for WordPress by Arne Brachhold http://www.arnebrachhold.de/redir/sitemap-home/ is a great sitemap generator. I have not noticed any difference in SEO by having two separate WordPress installs, with two separate sitemaps. To Googlebot, it's all the same website.

What sort of sitemaps do you plan on having? An XML file? An XML.GZ file? A static webpage with sitemap hyperlinks?

> “And should I have both the root URL and the blog subfolder URL showing
>   separately in Google Webmaster tools?” - ltm778

**ANSWER:**

You do not have to add sub-path urls to Google Webmaster tools, as the root url, once added, covers all urls of that root domain.